# Select distinct, show count at end of row

Tags: mysql, select, count, distinct

I have this table/data structure:

```
ID    Area       Postcode
------------------------
1     "Area 1"   "EN1 1NE"
2     "Area 2"   "AB2 3BA"
3     "Area 1"   "EN1 1NE"
4     "Area 3"   "XY4 5ZA"
5     "Area 4"   "MN6 5OP"
```

Rows 1 and 3 have duplicate Postcodes and Areas. I need a query that outputs counts like this this:

```
Area       Postcode    Count
----------------------------
"Area 1"   "EN1 1NE"   2
"Area 2"   "AB2 3BA"   1
"Area 3"   "XY4 5ZA"   1
"Area 4"   "MN6 5OP"   1
```

I've searched and played about with DISTINCT and/or COUNT and/or subqueries but getting really lost here! #weak-sql-fu

Thanks!
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use count(*) with group by like this:

```
select Area, Postcode, count(*) from TABLE group by Area, Postcode;
```

Answer (score 2):

have to use backtick within the `ALIAS` `COUNT` to escape the RESERVED WORD.

```
SELECT Area, 
       Postcode, 
       COUNT(ID) as `Count` 
FROM   tableName 
Group BY Area, Postcode
ORDER BY Area;
```